# Cocoapods: cannot find spec for pod even though it seems to exist

Tags: cocoapods

I have created my first Cocoapod and am trying to use it for the first time in a test program. Even though it shows up in "pod list", it is failing when I try "pod install" by saying "unable to find specification". Lint succeeded on the pod and I have pushed it to my private pod repo. I have also validated my private repo is listed in "pod repo list".

I found some similar threads on StackOverflow but nothing there seemed to help.

See below details.

**UPDATE:**

Based on Larme's comments I tried a few things:

1) Adding the below line at the top of the Podfile didn't have any effect:

> source 'ssh://git@code.mycompany.net/xmios/lib-mylib.git'

2) Removing the version number restriction didn't help.

3) Changing the Podfile to have the below *does* work:

> pod 'Lib-MYLIB', :git => 'ssh://git@code.mycompany.net/xmios/lib-mylib.git', :tag => '0.0.3'

Questions:

A) Why doesn't #1 work?

B) Why can't it search all the spec repos that are configured and find the pod itself?

**UPDATE 2:**

I found out that while I can specify a specific tag, I can't specify a version condition (for example >= 0.0.3), which is a significant drawback of approach #3, so I am looking for a method that allows me to do that.

**UPDATE 3:**

With some more experimentation, I found a good solution which involves using the "source" keyword as before, at the beginning of the Podfile. The problem was that I need to specify the podspec repo path there, not the path of the source itself.

> ===> in test program's Podfile
>
> target 'LibMYLIB_Consumer_Test' do
>
> pod 'Lib-MYLIB', '~> 0.0.3'
>
> end
>
> ===> in podspec for the pod:
>
> s.source       = { :git => "ssh://git@code.mycompany.net/ios/lib-mylib.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
>
> s.name         = "Lib-MYLIB"
>
> s.version      = "0.0.3"
>
> ===> Pod list
>
> ...
>
> Lib-MYLIB 0.0.3
>
> ...
>
> ===> pod install
>   --verbose   Preparing
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Inspecting targets to integrate   Using `ARCHS` setting to build
>   architectures of target `Pods-LibMYLIB_Consumer_Test`: (``)
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile` [!] Unable to find a specification
>   for `Lib-MYLIB (~> 0.0.3)`
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:461:in
>   `handle_resolver_error'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:80:in`
>   rescue in resolve'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:72:in
>   `resolve'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:771:in`
>   block in resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
>   `section'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:768:in`
>   resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:79:in
>   `analyze'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:242:in`
>   analyze'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in
>   `block in resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in`
>   section'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in
>   `resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in`
>   install!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in
>   `run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`
>   run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in
>   `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in`
>   ' /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`'

Comment: If you do `pod 'Lib-MYLIB'` instead of `pod 'Lib-MYLIB', '~> 0.0.3'` does it work? Also, at the beginning of your `podfile`, did you do `source 'ssh://git@code.mycompany.net/ios/lib-mylib.git`? Another possibility would be to do `pod 'Lib-MYLIB', :git => ssh://git@code.mycompany.net/ios/lib-mylib.git`

Comment: Thanks much, one of those solutions worked (See my update in the original post body), though it has a limitation so I am still looking for something else.

Comment: If you succeed by testing my propositions/hints and make it work, feel free to answer your own question with the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

With some more experimentation, I found a good solution which involves using the "source" keyword as before, at the beginning of the Podfile. The problem was that I need to specify the podspec repo path there, not the path of the source itself.

> source 'ssh://code.mycompany.net/ios/cocoapods.git'